# MapServer WFS Request via POST

Tags: wfs, mapserver, getfeature

Using MapServer 6.0.1-2

```
"<GetFeature                    
service="WFS"                    
version="1.1.0"                    
srsName="EPSG:900913"                    
xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"                    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs                     
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">                    
<Query typeName="clc_he_site_e" srsName="EPSG:900913">                        
<Filter>
<Intersects>
<PropertyName>the_geom</PropertyName>
<Point srsName="EPSG:900913">
<coordinates>-13898086.230923885,6532736.454751344</coordinates>
</Point>
</Intersects>
</Filter>                   
</Query>                
</GetFeature>"
```

The following WFS Request works flawlessly, but does not in
MapServer 6.4.1-2

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>MapServer Message</TITLE></HEAD>
<!-- MapServer version 6.4.1 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=GD SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=RSVG SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE -->
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: For some reason MapServer does not understand that you are making a WFS call. Does it work for you as GET? You are also trying to make a WFS 1.0.0 request with version="1.1.0" that should lead to an error but MapServer is maybe not so strict and obviously you do not even get so far. Current MapServer is v. 7.0.2, can you try also that?

Comment: It might be a change in axis order for coordinates, between those MapServer versions ~ https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/commit/7a5613e7b6355d5aeb564894d7df5ffca22460f8

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between between the two WFS schema.

- [WFS 1.0.0 xsd](http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd)
- [WFS 1.1.0 xsd](http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd)

The following WFS 1.0.0 GetFeature POST request is valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd" version="1.0.0" service="WFS">
   <wfs:Query typeName="clc_he_site_e">
       <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:Intersects>
             <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
             <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:900913">
                <gml:coordinates>-13898086.230923885,6532736.454751344</gml:coordinates>
             </gml:Point>
          </ogc:Intersects>
       </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

but a similar request against the WFS 1.1.0 schema is invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"
 xmlns:smil20="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/"
 xmlns:smil20lang="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <wfs:Query typeName="clc_he_site_e">
       <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:Intersects>
             <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
             <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:900913">
                <gml:coordinates>-13898086.230923885,6532736.454751344</gml:coordinates>
             </gml:Point>
          </ogc:Intersects>
       </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

The issue is that with WFS 1.1.0 `typeName="clc_he_site_e"` *Value 'clc_he_site_e' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '((\w:)?\w(=\w)?){1,}' for type 'TypeNameListType'.*

Tested using oXygen.

So it would appear that MapServer 6.4.1-2 is more strict in applying the WFS 1.1.0 schema rules than MapServer 6.0.1-2 is.